# Mutably iterate through an iterator using Itertools' tuple_windows

Tags: rust, iterator, rust-itertools

I'm attempting to store a series of entries inside a Vec. Later I need to reprocess through the Vec to fill in some information in each entry about the next entry. The minimal example would be something like this:

```
struct Entry {
    curr: i32,
    next: Option<i32>
}

struct History {
    entries: Vec<Entry>
}
```

where I would like to fill in the `next` fields to the next entries' `curr` value. To achieve this, I want to make use of the `tuple_windows` function from [Itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.circular_tuple_windows) on the mutable iterator. I expect I can write a function like this:

```
impl History {    
    fn fill_next_with_itertools(&mut self) {
        for (a, b) in self.entries.iter_mut().tuple_windows() {
            a.next = Some(b.curr);
        }
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a02c511ac25dba4b1a3de3974d341fd5))

However, it refuse to compile because the iterator `Item`'s type, `&mut Entry`, is not `Clone`, which is required by `tuple_windows` function. I understand there is a way to iterate through the list using the indices like this:

```
    fn fill_next_with_index(&mut self) {
        for i in 0..(self.entries.len()-1) {
            self.entries[i].next = Some(self.entries[i+1].curr);
        }
    }
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a02c511ac25dba4b1a3de3974d341fd5))

But I feel the itertools' approach more natural and elegant. What's the best ways to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.5/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows): 
`tuple_window` clones the iterator elements so that they can be part of successive windows, this makes it most suited for iterators of references and other values that are cheap to copy.

This means that if you were to implement it with `&mut` items, then you'd have multiple mutable references to the same thing which is undefined behaviour.

If you still need shared, mutable access you'd have to wrap it in `Rc<RefCell<T>>`, `Arc<Mutex<T>>` or something similar:

```rust
fn fill_next_with_itertools(&mut self) {
    for (a, b) in self.entries.iter_mut().map(RefCell::new).map(Rc::new).tuple_windows() {
        a.borrow_mut().next = Some(b.borrow().curr);
    }
}
```